# How to make the below element display above element on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, hover

How to make the below element display above element on hover?
I want something like

```
<div className="parent">
    <div className="hiddenElement"> Hey! </div>
    <div className="hoverElement"> Hover on me! </div>
</div>
```

But as far I as I searched, it is only possible with
`.parent:hover > .hey` and `.hiddenElement:hover + .hoverElement` . I tried `~` as well, but it doesn't work. I simply want my `hiddenElement` be on top of `hoverElement` by design. I tried to play with css margins, but it also didn't work, since my `hoverElement` is extendable input and its' size can grow. Also my `hiddenElement` is absolute. Simple design, input with hoverable div on top.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no previous sibling selector on CSS, so if you're able to change your markup slightly to:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="hoverElement"> Hover on me! </div>
    <div class="hiddenElement"> Hey! </div>    
</div>
```

These CSS rules would do what you're expecting:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.hiddenElement {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.hoverElement {
  position: absolute;
}

.hoverElement:hover {
  display: none;
}

.hoverElement:hover ~ .hiddenElement {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}

.hiddenElement {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.hoverElement {
  position: absolute;
}

.hoverElement:hover {
  display: none;
}

.hoverElement:hover ~ .hiddenElement {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="hoverElement"> Hover on me! </div>
    <div class="hiddenElement"> Hey! </div>    
</div>
```